# how to save only the id of the row being posted

Tags: php, mysql, html, post

I have a html table that I am populating with PHP, now it is populated and it has a button called 'update', there is also a field per row that has the 'client_id', also there are fields that have textboxes.

What I want to do now, is that if the user clicks on 'Update', it will post only those values for that row... How can i do this?, when they click 'Update' is it going to post all the fields of all the rows?, I just want the row where the update button was clicked.

Code below

```
print("<table id='results'><tr><th>ID</th><th>Image</th><th>Name</th><th>Price</th><th>Price Label</th><th>Description</th><th>Update</th></tr>");

 while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array( $result2 )){ 
     $client_id = $row2["client_id"];
     $client_name = $row2["client_name"];
     $client_disc = $row2["client_disc"];
     $client_price = $row2["client_price"];
     $client_image = $row2["client_image"];
     $client_price_label = $row2["client_price_label"];

     print("<tr>");   
     print("<td>");
     print("<p style='font-size:14px; color:blue; padding:0;'>$client_id</p>");
     print("</td>");          
     print("<td>");
     print("<img class='custom_rate' alt='' src='$client_image' />");
     print("</td>");
     print("<td width='100px'>");
     print("<input type='text' value='$client_name' name='clientname'/>");
     print("</td>");
     print("<td>");
     print("<input type='text' value='$client_price' name='clientprice'/>");
     print("</td>");
     print("<td width='100px'>");
     print("<input type='text' value='$client_price_label' name='clientpricelabel'/>");
     print("</td>");
     print("<td width='100px'>");
     print("<textarea cols='15' rows='2' name='description'>$client_desc</textarea>");
     print("</td>");
     print("<td width='100px'>");
     print("<input type='submit' value='Update' name='update'/>");
     print("</td>");
     print("</tr>");
}

print("</table>");
```

Comment: add a `<form>` tag to that row?

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel: Where can it be put where it is valid?

Comment: The form way, is not working.. I think other <form> from an include on another file is causing the issue but.. how can I do this with Ajax or Json.. or simply if I could just get a hold of the values when the 'update' button is clicked in that row.. i could then just do my stuff in php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make each row a form. However, this is going to be invalid HTML. Though, it'll still work.

I'd create some javascript to pull all of the values of the inputs within the row into a single json object, then send that object to the server via ajax.

jQuery would be my library of choice to do that, unless you have a larger app.

Hope that helps...

Updated: provided sample code to submit json for a row...

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $( '.submit_button' ).click(function(){

            var form_values = {};

            $( this ).closest( 'tr' ).find( 'input, select' ).each(function(){  
                form_values[ $(this).attr('name') ] = $(this).val();
            });
            if( form_values.undefined ){
                delete form_values.undefined;
            }

            $.post( "/test.php",
                form_values,
                function(data){
                    //success
                    alert( data );
                },
                "json"
            );

        });
    });
</script>
```

Update:

I wasn't happy with my previous answer, so I created a standalone html file to demonstrate that it works.

https://gist.github.com/1367465

You can't wrap a  tag around a , like the others are suggesting, because it'll break the html of the table.

Comment: Can you give me an idea of how i could achieve this using JSON and Javascript? maybe a small example if it is not much to ask?

Comment: thank you so much, so if my update button is called 'update' how would i change that code so that it uses Update and where would it know each field of the row? sorry new to this :)

Comment: Just add the "submit_button" css class to it. jquery will attach a click handler to all DOM elements with the "submit_button" class (or whatever class or id you query for).

Comment: so i can just do  print("<input type='submit' value='Update' name='update' class='submit_button'/>"); ? bare with me please..

Comment: Yes. BTW, you don't have to print everything. You can just end the php parsable section with ?> or use output buffering http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/13/7/0

Comment: Okay, great I will try this.. wow.. you dont sleep? lol.. i posted this at 4am or something.. gave up went to bed.. woke up at 8 and you are still here hehe :)

Comment: K thank you, one last question... so after i implement that is there anything else i need to take care of?

Comment: Plenty... but give it your best shot first. You can always post another question if you do get stuck.

Comment: yeah kinda stuck now lol.. i am not sure where it says "json" am i supposed to add something there? I added the function and the class to the input when i click on the 'Update' it does not cause anything.. i was expecting the alert.. :( what a noob i am

Comment: k i will post another question :)

Comment: @user710502 ... I updated it with a working file... hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Wrap all your separate rows in separate `<form>` tags. When you'll submit, only one `<form>` would be sent.

Another solution - you can use AJAX instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a `<form>` for every row and the action points to: `example.php?client_id=x`. In You PHP script, you can check that GET Param and the changed values (or you just use the client_id submitted by POST).

There's no other way afaik.

Answer (score 0):

Make separate form with unique name/id  for each row. And submit by javascript via button click (sending form name/id of respective row.)

```
function submitrow(id)
{
  document.forms[id].submit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want id of the row for which update button is clicked so that you can manipulate the id at server side. It might be a better idea to hava a function in Javascript

```
function update (id)
{

}
```

then call this function on onClick event of submit button and pass id as a parameter.

probably this is how you can do this, however you can check syntax

```
print("<input type='submit' value='Update' name='update' onclick=JavaScript:update('$client_id')/>");
```

update function will be called, there set the value of id in request and submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

You have several approaches here:

1. Make each row a form, so only that row gets submitted
2. Have a form composed entirely of hidden fields. Add a javascript event handler to each submit button that copies fields from the table into that form, and submits it
3. Variation on #2, instead of copying fields to a hidden form, build an AJAX request to submit data for only the single row

Comment: I would love do the AJAX request just not sure how to.. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

as i understand you want to update the separate records with the click on the update button, you also do this with jquery `.each()` event helps you to update the separate result. with the help of `.each()` start the loop and get the separate row with the update button.. but not sure that will work with the `<input type="submit" name="update" value="Update">`

use `<input type="button" name="update" value="Update">`

Answer (score 0):

```
     print("<form name="" action="your method to be triggered or url">" method="POST");
     print("<tr>");   
     print("<td>");
     print("<p style='font-size:14px; color:blue; padding:0;'>$client_id</p>");
     print("</td>");          
     print("<td>");
     print("<img class='custom_rate' alt='' src='$client_image' />");
     print("</td>");
     print("<td width='100px'>");
     print("<input type='text' value='$client_name' name='clientname'/>");
     print("</td>");
     print("<td>");
     print("<input type='text' value='$client_price' name='clientprice'/>");
     print("</td>");
     print("<td width='100px'>");
     print("<input type='text' value='$client_price_label' name='clientpricelabel'/>");
     print("</td>");
     print("<td width='100px'>");
     print("<textarea cols='15' rows='2' name='description'>$client_desc</textarea>");
     print("</td>");
     print("<td width='100px'>");
     print("<input type='submit' value='Update' name='update'/>");
     print("</td>");
     print("</tr>");
     print("</form>");
```

if you pass a url, then you can concat the client id and send it.